# accessing state after changing it with onchange return cyclic object value error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

good day everyone,

I'm currently working on a react-native project and i have a form where i update the state when something is written to the inputs.

when i later try to access my state i get a `cyclic object value` error.
after some research i found out that this is caused by the onchange method used on each of the text inputs (2).

below is my code and tried out solutions.

components:

```
<TextInput  
          onChange={uname => this.setState(/* { username: uname } */ updateUsername(uname))}
          placeholder={strings('login.username')}
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          onChange={pwd => this.setState(/* { password: pwd } */ updatePassword(pwd) ) }
          placeholder={strings('login.password')}
          style={[styles.input, styles.password]}
          secureTextEntry={true}
        />
        < TouchableOpacity onPress = { () => this.login()} >
          <Text style={styles.btn}>{strings('login.login')}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

as you can see from the comments inside the onchange prop of the textInput i did try 2 methods of updating the state:

i tried updating it the regular way by using the setState method on the component. then i tried defining 2 functions outside of the class then using them to update the class. neither solution made any difference.

```
const updateUsername = (username) => {
  return (prevState, currProps) => {
    return {...prevState, username}
  }
}

const updatePassword = (password) => {
  return (prevState, currProps) => {
    return {
      ...prevState,
      password
    }
  }
}

class Login extends Component {
  ....
}
```

this is the function where i get the error.it is defined inside the component class and is triggered when the button is clicked.

```
login() {
   console.log(this.state)
}
```

i was wondering if anyone has any idea on how to solve this issue.

thank you everyone in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onChangeText` instead of `onChange`.

`onChange` passes a `nativeEvent` object, while `onChangeText` just passes the string.